# Does Dockerfile creates one single image or multiple image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

My dock-compose.yml file

```
 db:
  image: postgres
  ports:
    - "5432"
web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
  volumes:
    - .:/myapp
  ports:
    - "3030:3030"
  links:
    - db
```

my Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.1.4
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y build-essential libpq-dev nodejs
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp
ADD Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
RUN bundle install
ADD . /myapp
# RUN bundle exec rake db:create
# RUN bundle exec rake db:migrate
# RUN bundle exec rake db:seed
```

when I run docker-compose up, it creates two containers, one with rails app and one with database. I was of the understanding that each docker file creates one final docker image (and hence one container)and but in this case we end up creating two different containers. Can someone explain it me, how is this happening ?

Answer (score 2):

The `docker-compose` manages two containers based on two images:

- The `postgres` container is based on an [existing image downloaded from Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/): no Dockerfile required for that one. If you don't have it locally, it will be downloaded, and kept [in your local image storage](http://blog.thoward37.me/articles/where-are-docker-images-stored/#local-storage-on-the-docker-host).
- the `web` one is based on your Dockerfile (because of the `build: .` directive)